# Quarkus reactive : test Mutli<Response>

Tags: java, rest, junit, junit5, quarkus

### Introduction

I'm working on a project that uses Quarkus Reactive.
And currently I made a method that returns a Multi, but I can't test this one.
I would like to ensure that all responses in the Multi have a code of 2XX.
And check the content of each answer.

### The codes:

```java
package com.xx.xx.xx.rest;


import com.xx.xx.xx.domain.customerprofile.CustomerProfileService;
import com.xx.xx.xx.infrastructure.binding.CustomerProfileMapper;
import com.xx.xx.xx.rest.annotation.ValidationGroups;
import com.xx.xx.xx.rest.dto.customerprofile.CustomerProfileDTO;
import com.xx.xx.xx.rest.exception.ErrorCode;
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Multi;
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.groups.ConvertGroup;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
import java.util.Collection;

/**
 * BulkImportResource is a rest resource class for bulk import of customer profiles.
 *
 * @version 1.0.0
 */
@Path("/bulkimport")
public class BulkImportResource {


    private final CustomerProfileService customerProfileService;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new Customer profile resource.
     *
     * @param customerProfileService the customer profile service
     */
    @Inject
    public BulkImportResource(CustomerProfileService customerProfileService) {
        this.customerProfileService = customerProfileService;
    }

    /**
     * Bulk import of customer profiles.
     *
     * @param customerProfileDTOs the list of customer profiles to import
     * @return the list of customer profiles
     */
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Multi<Response> postFormReturnAddedObject(@NotNull(message = ErrorCode.Constants.ERROR_EMPTY_BODY)
                                                             Collection<CustomerProfileDTO> customerProfileDTOs) {
        return Multi.createFrom().items(customerProfileDTOs.parallelStream())
                .onItem().transformToUniAndMerge(this::createCustomerProfileAndBuildResponse);

    }

    private Uni<Response> createCustomerProfileAndBuildResponse(
            @Valid @ConvertGroup(to = ValidationGroups.Post.class) CustomerProfileDTO customerProfileDTO) {
        return customerProfileService.createCustomerProfile(
                        CustomerProfileMapper.INSTANCE.dtoToDomain(customerProfileDTO))
                .map(CustomerProfileMapper.INSTANCE::domainToDTO)
                .map(dto -> Response
                        .created(UriBuilder.fromPath("customerProfiles/{id}")
                                .build(dto.getId()))
                        .entity(dto))
                .map(Response.ResponseBuilder::build);
    }
}
```

### The test:

```java
@QuarkusTest
@Tag("IntegrationTest")
@TestHTTPEndpoint(BulkImportResource.class)
@QuarkusTestResource(value = CouchbaseTestContainer.class)
public class BulkImportResourceIntegrationTest {
    private static final String JSON_FILE_NAME = "/profiles.json";
    private static File jsonFile;
    private List<CustomerProfileDTO> customerProfileDTOList;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUpAll() {
        jsonFile = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(MultipartBodyUnitTest.class.getResource(JSON_FILE_NAME)).getFile());
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        var objectWriter = new ObjectMapper();
        customerProfileDTOList = List.of(objectWriter.readValue(jsonFile, CustomerProfileDTO[].class));
    }

    @Test
    void createCustomerProfile() throws IOException {
        var responses = given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(customerProfileDTOList)
                .when().post()
                .then()
                .extract().as(Response[].class);
    }
}
```

*This test doesn't work, the returned error :*

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (String)"[{"status":201,"entity":{"id":"5","cas":1642517845455405056,"created":"2022-01-18T15:57:25Z","lastName":"DUPOND","firstName":"Marianne","gender":"FEMALE","title":"MRS","addresses":[{"street1":"rue du Testeur","zipCode":"34000","city":"MONTPELLIER","country":"France","typeKey":"PERSONAL"}],"phones":[{"number":"0610529856","typeKey":"PERSONAL"}],"emails":[{"email":"marianne.dupond@test.com","typeKey":"PERSONAL"}],"birthday":"1987-11-13","languages":["FR","EN"],"socialNetworks":[{"socialNetworkId":"[truncated 2143 chars]; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[][0])
```

### Outro

Someone have a solution for this problem ?

Comment: Using `Multi<Response>` won't work properly. We should actually disallow that. I'll take that up id I remember

Comment: @geoand do you have any solution to resolve this ?
The solution need to do not use `Multi<Response>` ?

Comment: As I said, `Multi<Response>` does not make sense and it will never work properly.